# How to check if column is present in Excel file while parsing in snaplogic

Tags: snaplogic

I have an Excel file and I want to insert the data into a database. I need to know if all the columns are present in the excel file. I used the required constraint of the data validator snap to be notified if a column is missing. But no error occurs when the column is missing. How to solve this please?

Answer (score 0):

If the number of columns in the excel file is fixed and you want to throw an error in case the columns don't match then you can simply use a `Mapper` snap and put all the column headers in the expression of the mapping table keeping the `Null-Safe Access` setting unchecked.

If you don't want to throw an error then check the `Null-Safe Access` setting and for each column name provide a default value.

For more information please refer to [SnapLogic Docs](https://docs-snaplogic.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SD/pages/1438286/Mapper).